# Problem with understanding how to scale a function

Tags: functions

[image]I'm trying to scale the following function:
$$y=\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a+bx}\times c}$$
For example, I want to scale it proportionately by 2. Turns out I need to multiply a and c by 4 (2 squared), but b by just 2. I assume this is something about square root and it also has to do with whether the constant is standing alone or being multiplied by x, but I'm not sure of what's actually going on and how to explain this. Can someone pls help?

Edit: for clarification, what I am trying to achieve is to keep the shape of the original function but scale the major axis of the half ellipse (domain 0, 4.2), not just scaling vertically or horizontally. Essentially trying to get the same shape with bigger size. As the screenshot shows, in order to scale it proportionately by 2, I had to multiply b by 2, but a and c had to be multiplied by 4.

[image: function scaled proportionately by 2]

Comment: In general to vertically scale a function $f$ by $s$, shouldn't you just use the function $s \cdot f(x)$? I don't see the need for those multiplications (and they, in fact, don't match up with what I envision scaling to mean, as one might see [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/umftt2lrcv))

Comment: To enclose a number of terms inside the radical, use {}.  If you click on "Edit" you'll see the exact syntax I used.

Comment: @PrincessEev I don't know if what I am doing is called scaling, but essentially what I am trying to achieve is to keep the shape of the original function but scale the major axis of the half ellipse (domain 0, 4.2), not just scaling vertically

Comment: @lulu Thank you

Comment: Can you [edit] to post a picture of what you have and what you want? Perhaps from desmos?

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes, now there is a screenshot. I already have what I want, I just don't know how to explain it.

Comment: I guess the mathematical term is "Homothety":https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothety

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to scale the graph of an equation in two variables $x,y$ by a constant factor $k$ one replaces each occurence of $x$ with $\frac{x}{k}$ and each occurence of $y$ with $\frac{y}{k}$. In your example to double the scale for both $x$ and $y$

$$y=\sqrt{1-\frac{x^{2}}{a+bx}\times c}$$

must be replaced with

$$ \frac{y}{2}=\sqrt{1-\frac{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2}}{a+b\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\cdot c}$$

Here is a [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mi7paycl9d) illustration.

Comment: Thank you. Is there an article/website about this method of scaling?

Comment: Thank you for your clever answer. I am not sure how to apply this same principle to a function like $Sin(x)$?

Comment: @Hengjiaren Go to my [precalculus](https://jwbales.us/precal/part1/part1.7.html) website and look at the sections on horizontal and vertical stretching and shrinking.,

Comment: @NoChance If you want to double both $x$ and $y$ scales for $y=\sin x$ you would use $\frac{y}{2}=\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$. That is, $y=2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$. Also, look at the link in my comment above for a more general answer.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, many thanks.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Thanks! That was really helpful

Comment: @Hengjiaren You are welcome.